# Не работает Событие DropDownList ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Не работает событие в DropDownList ASP.NET

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

Событие:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(ListItem item in DropDownList1.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Text + " | " + item.Value);
            }
        }
```

DropDownList заполняется вот так:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    ListItem item = new ListItem();
    item.Text = "asdasd"+i;
    item.Value = i;
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: а это новый проект? я к тому что вы в курсе, что использовать WebForms уже не стоит начинать?

Comment: @4per нет, для самообразования...

Comment: ну, тем более..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Включил AJAX на странице.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `AutoPostBack="true"`

Comment: Привет. попробовал уже, тупо перезагружает страницу, а событие не работает.

Comment: Проблема решена. Причиной решения стала включение ajax на странице.